# Problèm with SQL select grouping

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct, grouping, having

I have a small problem with a SQL Server query.

I have an issue with my view of several base tables with duplicate values, so far no problem, these duplicates are logical. By unfortunately I do not get the desired end result, I could do it by programming the front end of my application but I would prefer to do the work on the server.

I will explain the principle:
I have 30 companies which each have an employee table.
My view is a union of the 30 employee tables.
Each employee has a unique serial number, the number is the same across tables, so an employee named "John Doe" with an ID number 'S0000021' can be hired in Company A then transferred to company Q without any problems, it will retain the serial number 'S0000021'.

The difference between the data from the Employee tables A and Q will be in this example the start (hire) and release (transfer) dates entered for Company A and just the start date for company Q so the view will have 2 lines for "John Doe".

12 common fields are the following:

- Serial Number (Identical in every employee table)

  - Social Security Number (Same in every employee table)
  - Start/Hire Date
  - Release/Transfer date (empty/null if the employee is current)
  - Name (Can change across companies if the person divorces)
  - First name
  - Maiden name
  - Last Name
  - Gender
  - Final Released
  - Company Code

The problem seems simple that I would not appear that the latest information of the employee, except with a group by, if it has changed name or release date, it will be displayed twice.

I tried the following different ways but they don't return what I want

I returned results both ways but I always see duplicates because my dates within companies are never identical, and their name may change.

Sorry for this Google translation.

1 --

```
   select 
        vue.matricule,
        vue.numsecu,
        vue.name,
        vue.lastname,
        vue.maidenname,
        vue.secondname,
        vue.genre,
        vue.released,
        vue.companycode

    from
        vue

    group by 
        vue.matricule,
        vue.numsecu,
        vue.name,
        vue.lastname,
        vue.maidenname,
        vue.secondname,
        vue.genre,
        vue.released,
        vue.companycode
```

2---

```
select 
    distinct(vue.matricule),
    vue.numsecu,
    vue.name,
    vue.lastname,
    vue.maidenname,
    vue.secondname,
    vue.genre,
    vue.released,
    vue.companycode

from
    vue
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of source data and desired output? Show at least 2 or 3 employee scenarios.

Comment: My french is poor, but you want the max salary or most recent salary per employee per company, and each employee may have been in multiple companies, and each company is in its own table?  Your view unions the 30 employee tables together?

Comment: I think they are just looking for the latest record (probably by released date). Probably row_number with partitioning on employee id would work but I was hoping they could provide some sample data before answering :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the following:

- there is a view (vue) that already gathers all data from each of the 30 companies
- you are just looking for the latest record for each employee

If you need to also see a record for each name change we can change this.

```
--set up test data
declare @vue table (
    matricule       varchar(20),
    numsecu         varchar(20),
    name            varchar(20),
    lastname        varchar(20),
    maidenname      varchar(20),
    secondname      varchar(20),
    genre           varchar(20),
    start           datetime,
    released        datetime,
    companycode     varchar(20));

insert @vue values
    ('S0000021','123456789','John', 'Doe',null,null,'M','2015-01-01','2015-12-31','A'),
    ('S0000021','123456789','Johnny', 'Doe',null,null,'M','2016-01-01',null,'Q'),       --new company, name change, currently employed
    ('S0000022','123456780','Jane', 'Doe',null,null,'M','2015-01-01','2015-12-31','A'),
    ('S0000022','123456780','Jane', 'Doe',null,null,'M','2016-01-01','2016-02-01','Q'); --new company, name change, terminated

select * from @vue order by matricule, start;

--get latest record for each employee
select  *
from    (--add row numbering 
        select  *, row_number() over (partition by matricule order by start desc) row_num
        from    @vue
        ) vue2
where   vue2.row_num = 1;
```

Comment: Bonjour,
J'avais tourné la question dans tous les sens avec des sous requêtes mais celle-ci je ne l'avais pas imaginé.

Merci beaucoup le résultat donnée est celui que je cherchais.

Comment: Hello,
I had turned the matter in all directions with sub queries but this one I had not imagined.

Thank you very much given the result is the one I wanted.